# Sulu CMS: How to display a template hint in the admin view

Tags: sulu

my sulu 1.6 page template renders automatically a side navigation, if the page has sub-pages. Is there a way to display a content hint in the admin view?

I would imagine something like this:

[image: imagined content hint]

Is there a way to make this possible?

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but adding a text like this is currently not possible on a section. However, you can add an info text on a property like this:

```
<property name="endDate" type="date">
    <meta>
        <info_text lang="en">
            If the same as the start date, the event is treated a one-day event.
        </info_text>
    </meta>
</property>
```

Read more about that in [our documentation](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/templates.html?highlight=info_text#help-text).